# Is onSend now support on Outlook desktop?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to create an Outlook add-in with the onSend function. I can see on the GitHub [onSend Tutorial](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send) that onSend is only supported on Outlook web and 365. Has this been updated now (the readme is 2 years old)? I am trying to debug mine on Outlook desktop 2016 (using Visual Code + Edge extension) and the debugger never reaches the function I created and that is supposed to be reached during the onSend event.

If still not supported, can I still deploy this add-in via 365 (admin) and get it reflected on Outlook desktop 2016?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnSend is not supported in Outlook Desktop 2016.

Answer (score 0):

The `On-Send` feature is supported by the desktop editions of Outlook for Windows. Make sure you deal with the supported version of Windows, Exchange server, Outlook. Read more about that in the [On-send feature for Outlook add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows) article.